# Android BLE BluetoothDevice.autoConnect doen't work (Some of devices..)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two **Android Smart Phone(*Samsung Galuxy Note 4* - Android 5.0.1, *LG G Pad 8.3 WiFi* - Android 4.4.2)** and a BLE Peripheral Device and I had the BLE connection sample source from [Bluetooth SIG Developer Portal:Bluetooth Smart Starter Kit](https://developer.bluetooth.org/pages/smart-starter-kit.aspx). In this source use the method [BluetoothDevice.connectGatt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback)) when establishing connection between BLE Central(Android Device) and BLE Peripheral(Gatt Server) also the parameter of autoConnect in the connectGatt method set true like bellow.

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
```

That mean "Whether to directly connect to the remote device (false) or to automatically connect as soon as the remote device becomes available (true).".

**Then, I tried the test like below.**

**Step 1. Scan Advertisor in Android Device.**

**Step 2. Start Advertisment in Peripheral Device.**

**Step 3. Establish Connection between Android and Peripheral**

**Step 4. Put the Peripheral Device to out of connection available distance**

**Step 5. After get the disconnect sign, put Peripheral Device in connection available distance**

**Step 6. Check reconnection**

When I use the Samsung Galuxy Note 4, success autoConnection But LG G Pad couldn't autoConnection. Each Android device use the Bluetooth 4.0. I don't understand this situation.

I want to know what's the reason of the problem?

Comment: automatic reconnect feature is not consistent across different devices and vendors in my experience. So i ended up writing my own scan and reconnect code.